# Setting proxy username and password programmatically Android

Tags: android, https, proxy

Currently I am working on a application where I want to send request to server which is behind proxy. I found code to set proxy which is as below

```
HttpHost httpproxy = new HttpHost("ip",8080);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, httpproxy);
```

Now I want to set username and password. Does anyone know how to set username and password for proxy.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use credentials:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
new AuthScope("PROXY HOST", 8080),
new UsernamePasswordCredentials("your_username", "your_password"));
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("TARGET HOST", 443, "https");
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("PROXY HOST", 8080);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

but in my opinion that is a very unsafe way! You have to save the password anywhere on your android client. It is easy for a script-kiddy to determine that password.